# Отображение картинки в PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, изображения, pyqt

Мне нужно, чтоб в *PyQt5* вставить картинку, есть код, но он почему то не работает.

Название самой картинки  ввёл правильно, но не отображается.

Вот код:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow

SCREEN_SIZE = [400, 400]


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, *SCREEN_SIZE)
        self.setWindowTitle('Отображение картинки')
        
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('4543.JPEG')
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.move(80, 60)
        self.image.resize(250, 250)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: print(os.path.exists('4543.JPEG')) Что печатает?

Comment: os красным подчеркивается                                                                                                
  (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/av_manager/PycharmProjects/task 2000/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(os.path.exists('4543.JPEG'))
NameError: name 'os' is not defined)

Comment: добавьте в импорты `import os`

Comment: False выводит  ..

Comment: добавьте скрин с папкой проекта, это должно быть что-то с картинкой

Comment: ну так я другие картинки пробовал, ни одна не идёт

Comment: Если False значит нет этого файла или не верный путь

Comment: Кстати что за OS у вас? На Андроид кстати надо абсолютный путь указывать.

Comment: image_path = os.path.abspath('4543.JPEG')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код написан правильно. Я думаю, что проблемы с изображением, попробуйте вставить другое.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        self.setGeometry(400, 400, *SCREEN_SIZE)
        self.setWindowTitle('Отображение картинки')
        
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('lena.jpg').scaled(250, 250)    # + .scaled(250, 250)
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.move(80, 60)
        self.image.resize(250, 250)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


SCREEN_SIZE = (400, 400)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys                                                # +++
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(*SCREEN_SIZE)                                   # + 
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробывал картинку как у вас, всё равно не отображает

Comment: @Алексей а изображение с расширением `.png` ?

Comment: и с .png пробывал и .jpg. Не так, не так не идёт

Comment: @Алексей сохраните изображение из моего ответа как `testlena.png` в папку откуда вы запускаете программу. Исправьте в `self.pixmap = QPixmap('testlena.png').scaled(250, 250)` и запустите.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: если не получится, расскажите как вы запускаете программу - с CMD/терминала/консоли и покажите строку запуска. Какая у вас ОС ? И покажите полный путь к изображению.

Comment: получилось, только теперь другая проблема. Там есть картинка, но просто набор RGB пикселей, а не нормальная картинка

Comment: так, вроде всё получилось. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Алексей пожалуйста.